# why static Database _database; and DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor(); gives an error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper{
  static final _dbName= 'myDatabase.db';
  static final _dbVersion=1;
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance=DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static Database _database;

  Future <Database> get database async{
    if(_database!=null)return _database;

        return _database;
  }
}
```

why static Database _database; and   DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor(); gives an error???

Answer (score 1):

change

```
static Database _database;
```

to

```
static Database? _database;
```

because of null safety feature (recent update in flutter).

And also you will need to change

```
Future <Database> get database async{
    if(_database!=null)return _database;
       return _database;
  }
```

to

```
Future <Database> get database async{
    return _database ??= await initDB();
}
```

initDB() is a function to initialise the database.